# jQuery: Hide parent <td> if contains child <input> with specific class?

Tags: jquery, parent-child, html-table

I'm working with the jQuery Tablesorter Filters plugin and I'm trying to hide certain `<td>`. This is what I'm looking to do:

-If `<td>` contains `<input class="tablesorter-filter disabled">`, hide the parent `<td>`

```
<tr class="tablesorter-filter-row">
    <td>
        <input class="tablesorter-filter">
    </td>

    <td>
        <input class="tablesorter-filter disabled">
    </td>

    <td>
        <input class="tablesorter-filter">
    </td>
</tr>

<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $(".tablesorter-filter-row td").filter(function(i) { return $(this).find("> input.disabled").length > 0 }).hide();
    });
</script>
```

That is the jQuery I culled from another issue I had, but it's not hiding the parent td in this instance.

Comment: Your code should work. What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Edited OP to clarify: "code is not hiding parent td".

Comment: Where is the code? Is it in an event handler, in the ready handler, or just top-level JS code?

Comment: Try this `$('input.disabled').each(function () { $(this).closest('td').hide(); });`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code look fine. Make sure you do this in **DOM ready handler** and it should work fine.

```
$(function() {
   $(".tablesorter-filter-row td").filter(function() {
         return $('input', this).hasClass('disabled');
    }).hide();
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/hyXwV/)**

Comment: Is that better than `$('input.disabled', this).length > 0)`?

Comment: OP's code works. You could've also just written `$('.tablesorter-filter-row td:has(input.disabled)').hide();`. The problem isn't here.

Comment: Rite.. looks like he is not defining his code from inside the `DOM ready event` as his code must be before the HTML has been defined

Comment: One more issue might be that he is not nesting the `tr's` inside the `table` element in the first place. If he does that then neither of the code works

Comment: The code is in a Wordpress page and is being called after the HTML is defined. I edited the OP to show how the script is called after the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.tablesorter-filter-row td').each(function(){
if($(this).children('input').hasClass('disabled').length == 0)
{
    $(this).children('input').hide();
}
});
```