# Hide parent if child contains class

Tags: javascript

I followed this [jQuery: Hide parent <td> if contains child <input> with specific class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532109/jquery-hide-parent-td-if-contains-child-input-with-specific-class#16532145) but its not working in my code:

```
$(function() {
$(".video-list-item").filter(function() {
     return $('span', this).hasClass('.view-count');
}).hide();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xzeeuotL/

Comment: Please describe what exactly you're trying to achieve

Comment: **hasClass('view-count')**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Two things to fix but you were close.

1) You did not include `Jquery` as a library for the JSFiddle

2) In the `hasClass` method you need to remove the `.` in the class name

```
$(function() {
$(".video-list-item").filter(function() {
     return $('span', this).hasClass('view-count');
}).hide();
});
```

Here is a working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/rn2jzpfc/

Answer (score 1):

You were close. Just one mistake in your code.
When you are checking if something `hasClass` there is no need to have the `.` preface it.

Also remember you need to include jquery.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".video-list-item").filter(function() {
    return $('span', this).hasClass('view-count');
  }).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-list-item">
  <span class="view-count">HIDE THIS</span>
</div>
<div class="video-list-item">
  <span>DON'T HIDE THIS</span>
</div>
```

**You can do this without Jquery**

Here is an example using pure javascript.

```js
var divSel = document.querySelectorAll('.video-list-item > .view-count');

for (var i = 0; i < divSel.length; i++) {
  divSel[i].parentElement.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="video-list-item">
  <span class="view-count">HIDE THIS</span>
</div>
<div class="video-list-item">
  <span>DON'T HIDE THIS</span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The next code returns the parent with `video-list-item` class of elements with `view-count` class; then hide the parent. I thinks it's more easy than your approach:

```
$(".view-count").closest('.video-list-item').hide();
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tomloprod/xzeeuotL/2/

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
$(function() {
    $('.video-list-item').find('span.view-count').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change that syntax for your case.

you have to be sure that your `<td>` has a class name like ".video-list-item" and later change in the `$('span', this)` for `$('input', this)`, of course, you input would has a class name like `view-count`. something like this..

```
$(function() {
$(".video-list-item").filter(function() {
     return $('input', this).hasClass('view-count');
}).hide();
});


<td class="video-list-item">
 <input class="view-count">
</td>
```

i hope it can help you.. nice day!!

Answer (score 0):

Useful thing if you want to remove closest parent that contains child with specific class:

```
<div class="closest_parent">
    <div></div>
    <div class="child_class"></div>
</div>
$('.child_class').closest('.closest_parent').remove();
```